# Flex Blazeds JavaIntegration

Tags: java, apache-flex, ms-access, flex3, blazeds

I have a java program running on my system which connects to MS Access for login page validation.

How do I trigger this particular java code from flex 3 using blazeds?

I am using bea weblogic application server (as a web server).

Answer (score 2):

Export you JavaCode as HttpService i.e...

`<s:HTTPService id="srv" url="url" result="data=method u want to call if it returns some data"/>  -->`

Now suppose u want to call the method getAllNames() on CreationComplete event than simply you can have your view declaration as

`<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="Home"
        xmlns:dao="dao.*" creationComplete="data=srv.getAll()">`

Hope that works.. I have also started learning Flex just few days back, Better you take a look at this [excellent tutorial](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/employee-directory-android-flex.html)

Answer (score 1):

Expose your Java Code as a web service and access it using RemoteObject. WebService, or HTTPService.

Answer (score 0):

Download BlazeDS http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/blazeds/BlazeDS
Then you can follow the guides. 
I'm using Tomcat. Just extract the blazeds war file into webapp folder, and then start your server, find the flex folder generated. Check remoting-config.xml, where you can expose your services. Then your flex side can call these services.